# Javascript calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I am working on a simple availability/booking system for a small hostel and am looking for a useful javascript/jquery calendar.

I need this calendar to render available/blocked dates, a user has to be able to select dates (date range) and possibly the calendar has the ability to display days in different range (1row x31 days, 2rows x16days, multiple months)

I spent some time trying to configure .net calendar, but did not get the results I wanted.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 7):

[FullCalendar jQuery Plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) is probably the most flexible one out there.

Answer (score 4):

[jQueryUI has a datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) which is probably exactly what you want

Comment: not really, I am not looking for a datepicker, just a plain calendar with the functions I mentioned. Something like the calendar on http://www.holidaysitecentral.com/eng/holiday-booking-calendar.php?lngc=&caltyp=1

Answer (score 2):

Look at YUI Calendar?
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/calendar/

or DynArch
http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar

or use Jquery UI

Comment: DynArch calendar is interesting, but dont think that is what I am looking for. Thanks for help